# Calling MATLAB functions in python

Tags: python, matlab, python-import, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

Problem occurred while calling MATLAB function in python after importing the MATLAB functions as a python package. Error shown in python shell:

[image]

Here, `barcode` is the name of the package generated using MATLAB library compiler and `barcodepy` is a function in the package.

Comment: You imported `barcode` and then tried to use `barcodepy`. This has nothing to do with MATLAB and only has to do with `barcodepy` not being defined. Try `from barcode import barcodepy`

Comment: Thank you for your response mate. I used from barcode import barcodepy, however, another error occurred when I did this.  ImportError: cannot import name 'barcodepy'

Comment: Please provide a minimal example that causes the error and the full text of the error produced.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to use `barcodepy` for example:

Your code :

```
import barcode

a=barcodepy.initialize()

a=barcode.barcodepy.initialize()
```

---

Correct code:

```
import barcode

a=barcode.initialize()
```